# Improve mic sensitivity; phone partner can't hear me

Tags: calls, volume-control, microphone

Whenever I use my phone to actually call someone, I often hear the complaint that I'm speaking too low, even when I'm using a loud enough voice. **Is there a way to increase the sensitivity of the mic, or to boost the volume?**

This problem is bad enough when using the phone without accessories, but if I use my iPhone 4 headset I have to nearly swallow the mic to be heard. My Bluetooth headset is as bad as the phone but better than the Apple headset.

I'm using a Nexus 4 and this has been the problem on every software release: Android 4.0, 4.1, 4.2, 4.2.2, and CM 10.1.3. My searches haven't revealed any solution, but it seems to be a problem on many different brands and models, not specific to my current hardware or software.

Comment: Are you sure you're not the victim of a practical joke; they can all hear you perfectly?

Comment: @Poldie: Yes, I'm sure. I get that complaint from everybody, including businesses I am calling.

Comment: What if it's a hardware defect?

Comment: Also on a Nexus 4, but my experience is wildly different from yours. Perhaps @geff is actually on to something and your device might be a dud. However, the headset weirdness you have kind of makes that theory hard to digest.